# Wordpress Custom post type list categories & list post of active category

Tags: php, conditional-statements, wordpress

I can list all my custom post type categories and there posts however I only want to list the posts of the current category.

```
<?php

$post_type = 'product';
$tax = 'product_category';
$tax_terms = get_terms($tax, array('orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC'));
if ($tax_terms) {
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'caller_get_posts' => 1
        ); 
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h3>' . $tax_term->name . '</h3>';
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        ?>
      <p><i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="margin-right:5px;"></i><?php the_title(); ?>       </p>

      <?php
        endwhile;
    } 
    wp_reset_query();
} 
} 

?>
```

This will list all of the categories in my custom post type like I wanted however displays all posts and not just those related to the current category.

Below is some code that I found of the web which will display the post of the active category. I have tried to combine the two but my lack of php and conditional loops mean I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<?php

$tax = get_query_var('tax'); // get current category
$yourcat = get_category($cat);

// now get all 'business' posts that are in the current custom taxonomy 
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_category' => $yourcat->slug ) ); 

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Hope someone can help me and either combine the two pieces of code or tell me a new option.

For example if I was on a page showing DVD results I want a sidebar displaying other categories and below the DVD heading in the sidebar display the titles (posts) within the DVD category.

DVD

-TITLE

-TITLE2

-TITLE3

BLU-RAY

CD

Answer (score 0):

did you do `'hierarchical' => true`, when registering your post type?

It should look something similar to this on your functions.php

```
// Custom Post_type Products
    add_action( 'init', 'create_products' );
    function create_products() {
         $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Products', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Product', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Product'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add new product'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit product'),
        'new_item' => __('New product'),
        'view_item' => __('View product'),
        'search_items' => __('Search product'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No products found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No products found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
      );

      $supports = array('title', 'editor', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes' );

      register_post_type( 'Products',
        array(
          'labels' => $labels,
          'public' => true,
          'supports' => $supports,
          'hierarchical' => true,
          'menu_position' => 6, // places menu item directly below Posts
          'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-cart',
          'has_archive' => true
        )
      );
    }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Yeah I have that but what I want is to show all categories in a list under the active one display a list of posts under it.